# What does this segue error mean?

Tags: objective-c, segue

I get this error when a modal segue takes place:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GameOver: 0x7ffc7b714280> on <Playing_Page: 0x7ffc7b7128b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Can someone explain to me what this means, and which `View` isn't in the window hierarchy. Also, possible ways I would accidentally remove a `view` from the hierarchy, and how to avoid doing so.

I don't want an answer that fixes the problem, I just want some info on what this error means and how to *avoid* it.

Note: I have looked this up, and usually the results are just about solving it, i.e. `viewDidAppear` at least all the ones I looked at.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Warning: Attempt to present <GameOver: 0x7ffc7b714280> on <Playing_Page: 0x7ffc7b7128b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
> ```
>
> Can someone explain to me what this means, and which View isn't in the window hierarchy

It means exactly what it says. You have a view controller called Playing_Page and a view controller called GameOver. You told Playing_Page to `presentViewController:GameOver`. But Playing_Page's view is not in the view hierarchy at this moment (meaning it is not part of the interface; putting it another way, it is not visible, although that's much less technically accurate - what the error message said is the best way to understand it). So it can't present anything.

Basically you cannot tell a view controller to present anything unless that view controller has itself already been pushed, or presented, or somehow gotten its view correctly into the interface.

Comment: Does this mean that I have dismissed `Playing_Page` to early when trying to segue to `GameOver`. Or did something go wrong before with `Playing_Page`?

Comment: Oh come on, @Minestrone-Soup. First of all, how on earth do I know? You didn't show any code at all. None. I have no idea what you might have done. Do you think people can read your mind? Second, you specifically said "I don't want an answer that fixes the problem, I just want some info on what this error means." I gave you that info. I have given you enough info for you to focus on your code and (gasp) debug it. So my suggestion is that you go do that.